# Cassandra Process Killed by OS

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using apache cassandra server. After random amount of time my cassandra service stops. when I try to check its status using 'service cassandra status' using centOS7 it shows me the following log

```
[centos@ip-172-31-24-101 routes]$ service cassandra status

cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-12-31 10:26:13 UTC; 34min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Main PID: 2078 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Dec 31 05:12:46 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal su[781]: (to cassandra) root on none

Dec 31 05:12:49 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal cassandra[761]: Starting Cassandra: OK

Dec 31 05:12:49 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.

Dec 31 10:25:46 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: cassandra.service: main process exited, code=killed, s...KILL

Dec 31 10:25:47 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal su[15760]: (to cassandra) root on none

Dec 31 10:25:47 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal cassandra[15746]: Shutdown Cassandra: bash: line 0: kill: (2078) - ...ess

Dec 31 10:26:13 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal cassandra[15746]: ERROR: could not stop cassandra

Dec 31 10:26:13 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: cassandra.service: control process exited, code=exited...us=1

Dec 31 10:26:13 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit cassandra.service entered failed state.

Dec 31 10:26:13 ip-172-31-24-101.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: cassandra.service failed."
```

How can I figure out what wrong with the Cassandra? why its crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process being killed by SIGKILL is often the result of Linux's "OOM Killer" - which kills processes when running out of memory (see, for example, 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short/136294 for some more details on the OOM Killer).

This may indicate that you are giving too much memory to Cassandra (for both heap and off-heap), don't have enough swap space, or both. If it's the OOM killer which killed you r Cassandra, you should be able to find log messages in the usual places (dmesg, /var/log/messages, journalctl, depending on your distribution). Messages which look something like:

```
[   54.125380] Out of memory: Kill process 8320 (cassandra) score 324 or sacrifice child
[   54.125382] Killed process 8320 (cassandra) total-vm:1309660kB, anon-rss:1287796kB, file-rss:76kB
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the system.log for the Cassandra process as it should point you to where the problem is.  Depending on if you installed C* from a package or a tarball will depend where it is located.  The default for a package install is /var/log/cassandra and for a tarball I think it is installation_directory/log/cassandra (not positive on this).